# How tosave Image in DataBase Using JSON WebService WP7

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I want to save Image in Database with JSON web service .without image data save.
But when  send image byte It is not save. How to send or Recive Image with JSon webservie in window phone-7

My Webservice:

```
    [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
            public string Register(string emailID, string pwd, string name, string img)
            {
                ProfileDL _client = new ProfileDL();

                _client.Email = emailID;
                _client.Password = pwd;
            img = img.Replace(' ', '+');
            _client.Firstname = name;
            _client.Img = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
            _client.saveData();
            return "Y";
        }

WP7 Code:-



    //Convert Image to byte code
     private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        { 
     imageBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
     e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    }

 void GetRequestStreamCallbackx(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
            string img = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                 img = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            }
            catch { }
            // Create the post data
         // string postData = "";
             var json="";

              Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => json = "{\"emailID\": " + txtemail.Text.Trim() + ",\"pwd\": " + txtpassword.Text + ",\"name\":" + txtname.Text + ",\"img\": " + img + "}");


          byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // Add the post data to the web request
            try
            {
                postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            catch { }
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the web request
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
        }
```

there is any thing wrong in my code. Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess: an empty request is being made?

If you just use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to set the `json` variable, it probably will be set after the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)` call!

Try it like this:

```
void GetRequestStreamCallbackx(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    // End the stream request operation
    Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    string img = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        img = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    }
    catch { }
    // Create the post data
    // string postData = "";
    var json = "";

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        json = "{\"emailID\": " + txtemail.Text.Trim() + ",\"pwd\": " + txtpassword.Text + ",\"name\":" + txtname.Text + ",\"img\": " + img + "}";


        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        try
        {
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        catch { }
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks sir I have change code according to you but   return error  "AsyncWaitHandle = 'asynchronousResult.AsyncWaitHandle' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'"

Comment: Ok, then just try to get the json value before doing the hole request! That should fix the problem!